# VSCode: How to navigate inside JS "require"?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I would like to be able to click on the filepath below to open the file that the path references.

**`const foo = require('services/api/bar')`**

Does VS Code offer "out-of-the-box" support for this feature? Or can support be gained from an extension?

Comment: Have you tried holding down Ctrl then clicking?

Comment: yep, doesn't work

Comment: you'd use proper relative dirs (because as written, you're requiring `api/bar` from a module called `services` instead of importing a local file), and then ctrl-click/cmd-click (depending on your OS) will work just fine.

Comment: that is not something I can change as it is not my codebase

Comment: Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is right. I think it is the way your formatting the pathnames. There is no leading dot or dots (_.i.e._ '.', '..'). There is no file extension, and its a module being referenced I guess. (points to Mike for knowing that off the top of his head).

Answer (score 0):

## Open File From Path

---

> #### Edit:
>
> Originally when I answered this, I thought VS Code didn't support this feature because it doesn't work for me. Turns out, it doesn't work for several people. I have changed my answer to explain how support can be gained for everyone.

---

### OUT-OF-THE-BOX SUPPORT

**V.S. Code** offers support *"out-of-the-box"*, however, it does not work for everyone. There are various reasons why people experience issues with the native vscode feature. The most common is because VS Code implements a keybinding that is unique to VS Code (example below):

**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>CLICK</kbd>**

The Mouse Keybinding can sometimes interfere with an Operating System, or with other software. If you are having an issue getting the default feature to work, not all is lost. Support can be gained through the extension that I have named below.

- **Extension's Name:** Open File From Path
- **Extension's ID:** `"jack89ita.open-file-from-path"`

###### *The extension should work immediately after installation with no need to restart your instance of VS Code.*

---

### Instructions on Using the Extension:

After the extension is installed, use your mouse to click on the path you wish to navigate to. After you have clicked on the desired path you will use **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>** to navigate to the path's file.

I personally prefer to alter the keybindings that the extension offers by default

Comment: You really want to tone down all this huge, bold, and italic text.

Comment: Don't use too many bold headings, as it makes it harder to interpret your answer.

Comment: I use bold heading in the exact format that they are suppose to be used. Querry engines expect a certain hierarchy, and it should be used, as it helps people find the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, that extension made it somewhat easier. However, instead of jumping directly into the file, it shows me a list of files with similar path, e.g:
js/services/api/bar.js

test/services/api/bar.spec.js

public/services/api/bar.html

Why cannot it resolve the path the same way as js does?

Comment: Thats odd, it jumps straight to the path for me. The filepath didn't have an file ext in your question, maybe that is why? Obviously it can't jump to a directory.

Comment: IDK, its probably the way that the developer wrote it. If you read the docs, he is using regex for some of the configurations he mentions at the bottom of the extensions README.md. If he resolves it using Regular Expressions, rather than the Node.js FS library, it probably won't resolve the same. It works for me without opening a list, so that's odd.